# explicit-function-return-type creating functional component react in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
const App: FC = () => {
   const addItem = () => {
      useState([...items, {id:1,name:'something'])
   }
   return<div>hello</div>
}
```

linter gave me error, on my App.tsx.

```
warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
```

I have to turn off explicit-function-return-type, how to fix above code? The AddItem doesn't have to return something.

Comment: What's the error exactly?

Comment: @deceze warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which version of react are you using, but the so-called right way of providing typings for your Functional Components using TypeScript and React 16.8 would be to use `React.FC` or `React.FunctionComponent`. The following would run fine on most `TsLint` configs. You can try using the below on your project that runs on `@typescript-eslint`

```
import * as React from 'react';

const App: React.FC = () => {
   // do something

   return <div>hello</div>;
}
```

However, if the above does not work, you may be required to explicitly type the return value by doing the following:

```
import * as React from 'react';

const App: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
   // do something

   return <div>hello</div>;
}
```